# Has anyone been able to nicely integrate the ACE editor into reveal.js?

Tags: ace-editor, reveal.js

[This](https://github.com/kljensen/go-is-awesome) is the closest I've seen to that, and even it doesn't do a particularly good job; it certainly doesn't integrate (if it can even be said to do so) as well as the the highlight.js blocks reveal.js supports by default (which aren't responsive and lack a bunch of the other nice features of ACE).

I tried naively embedding an ACE textbox in a slide myself, and it didn't work out well. Reveal changed the size of the thing, but even after fixing that (and setting "text-align:left") the visual cursor didn't align with the actual cursor, and the editor warning icon was tiny.

Comment: Could you show your code, this must be error with calling editor resize

Answer (score 1):

The problem with ACE and reveal.js is the are the css attributes `zoom` or `transform: scale()` which reveal uses to fit the content to the screen. ACE requires pixel fonts and does not use the scaling in calculating mouse cursor positions.

I made a small fork and added a reval.js specific check for the editor.

see https://github.com/waywaaard/ace
https://github.com/waywaaard/ace/commit/e4e3da28515ef7a58fe85378dd4dd557918fc4a6

This fixes the problem for my use cases.

Comment: No, those changes are really specific for reveal.js

Answer (score 1):

My way of solving those issues is embedding ACE in an iframe instead of using it directly. I wrote a reveal.js plugin that makes embedding an ACE editor easy:

https://github.com/Gottox/reveal.js-ace